# How do I repeat my iteration if the user has not answered yes or no

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and am doing some basic code. I need to know if i can repeat my iteration if the answer is not yes or no. Here is the code (sorry to those of you that think that im doing bad habits). I need the iteration to repeat during else. (The function just outputs text at the moment)

```
    if remove_char1_attr1 = 'yes':
        char1_attr1.remove(min(char1_attr1))
        char1_attr1_5 = random.randint(1,6)
        char1_attr1.append(char1_attr1_5)
        print("The numbers are now as follows: " +char1_attr1 )
    elif remove_char1_attr1 = 'no'
        break
    else:
        incorrect_response()
```

Comment: You can use `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the code into a loop:

```
while True: 
    if remove_char1_attr1 = 'yes':
        char1_attr1.remove(min(char1_attr1))
        char1_attr1_5 = random.randint(1,6)
        char1_attr1.append(char1_attr1_5)
        print("The numbers are now as follows: " +char1_attr1 )
    elif remove_char1_attr1 = 'no'
        break
    else:
        #incorrect_response()
        print("Incorrect")
```

then it will run till the `remove_char1_attr1` is "no"

Answer (score 0):

You can try looping while it's not yes or no

```py
while remove_char1_attr1 not in ('yes', 'no'):    
    if remove_char1_attr1 = 'yes':
        char1_attr1.remove(min(char1_attr1))
        char1_attr1_5 = random.randint(1,6)
        char1_attr1.append(char1_attr1_5)
        print("The numbers are now as follows: " +char1_attr1 )
    elif remove_char1_attr1 = 'no'
        break
    else:
        incorrect_response()
```